# php error message when success store in db

Tags: php, mysql

I have code for store some data to data base. Before edit its success store database but problem is when I am refresh duplicate data.

I am edited and worked without any problem but when I press submit and store data to db I get an message error > why ?

this is form code (index.php)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Proposals Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="columns.css" />
</head>

<body bgcolor="#3AA0BC">
<table border="5">
<form action="enterinfo.php" method="post"><br /><br />
<center> FirstName :<br /><input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" size="25"><br /><br/>
Title :<br />&nbsp;<textarea name="title" id="title" size="50"></textarea></center>
<p><th><input type=submit value="OK" name="submit" id="submit"class="buttStyle"></th</p>
</form>

<form action="view.php" method="post">
<p><th><input type=submit value="عرض المواظيع" class="buttStyle"></th></p></form>
<form action="addcomment.php" method="post">
<p><th><input type=submit value="اضافة تعليق" class="buttStyle"></th></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and enter code is (enterinfo.php)

```
<?php
include ("connect.php");
$Name=isset($_POST['Name']) ?
$_POST['Name'] : '';
$title=isset($_POST['title']) ?
$_POST['title'] : '';
$submit = isset($_POST['submit']) ? 
$_POST['submit'] : '';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 if($Name && $title)
 {
  $result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO subject(S_Id,Name,title)
                                     VALUES(NULL, '$Name', '$title')");  
  header('Location: enterinfo.php');

 }
}
 if($result)
{
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
}
else
{
echo "error";
}
?>
```

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: Well most likely with the refresh you send the form a second time. That means the `INSERT` is attempted a second time, which fails because of some primary key which would be doubled.

Comment: no problem with stor data.but why i get error message not Successful

Comment: Don't redirect. You will get message `Successful`.

Comment: when remove  header('Location: enterinfo.php'); i get duplicate data when i  refresh page

Comment: @Rikesh OP is getting error message because the insert query is not executing as the OP is passing NULL value for the column which is supposed to be a primary key column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set a variable in your url after executing your query(i have used re) and check at the top of your page if re exists then echo your message based on re value and exit.
Change your enterinfo.php like below code
Try this:

```
  if(isset($_REQUEST['re'])){   
    $message = $_REQUEST['re'] == 'success' ? "Sucessfully inserted" : "can not  inserted";   
    echo $message;
    exit();
  }




include ("connect.php");
$Name=isset($_POST['Name']) ?
$_POST['Name'] : '';
$title=isset($_POST['title']) ?
$_POST['title'] : '';
$submit = isset($_POST['submit']) ? 
$_POST['submit'] : '';

 if(isset($_POST['submit']) )
    {
     if($Name && $title)
     {
      $result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO subject(Name,title)
                                         VALUES('$Name', '$title')");  
     if($result){
       header('Location: enterinfo.php?re=success');
      }
      else{
        header('Location: enterinfo.php?re=fails');
       }   
     }
    }
```

Comment: ok i get success but when i refresh page i get duplicate data in database

Answer (score 0):

```
$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO subject(S_Id,Name,title)
VALUES(NULL, '$Name', '$title')");
```

in the above query of yours i think **S_Id is a primary key so it cant be NULL**.change your above code to and set **S_Id to autoincrement**

So your insert query should look like:

```
$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO subject(Name,title)
                                     VALUES('$Name', '$title')");
```

Answer (score 0):

after data update, your are redirecting again same page...

```
 header('Location: enterinfo.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

for update a value into a table you should use something like this:
UPDATE table
SET column1 = expression1,
    column2 = expression2,
    ...
WHERE conditions;

you cannot "INSERT" a row two times if it contains the same value for a UNIQUE field (like for example the ID)

Answer (score 0):

after data update, your are redirecting again same page...

header('Location: enterinfo.php');

remove header('Location: enterinfo.php'); and then check

Comment: when remove it, i get duplicate data when i refresh page

Comment: @nasr25 you need to keep the header in the if statement or else part

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
     if($Name && $title)
     {
      $result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO subject(Name,title)
                                         VALUES('$Name', '$title')");  
     if($result){
      $msg="Successful";
       
      }
      else{
        $msg="error";
       }   
     }

header('Location: index.php?msg=$msg');

    }



after that echo $_GET['msg'] in index.php

Comment: message are display in index.php page put <?php echo $_GET['msg'];?>